# How can I set up the working directory and the local repository on different drives?

Tags: git, backup

In Git, how can I set up the working directory and the local repository on different drives?
The reason being to back up code on every local commit.

We employ a gatekeeper model on the 'master' repository, so I can't just push any old rubbish upstream, but I would like to ensure that any old rubbish is backed up every time I make a local commit.

Comment: Has the repository already been initialised? Or are you about to create a new one for another project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `git init`'s `--separate-git-dir` flag

The [`git init`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) command has a flag for that:

> `--separate-git-dir=<git dir>`
>
> Instead of initializing the repository as a directory to either
>   `$GIT_DIR` or `./.git/`, create a text file there containing the path
>   to the actual repository. This file acts as filesystem-agnostic Git
>   symbolic link to the repository.

## Example

For this example, let's assume that `/Volumes/My_USB/` is the path to a USB drive. (`/Volumes` is specific to Mac OS, but, other than this path, this example translates to other operating systems in a straightforward manner.)

To initialise a Git repository

- whose working tree is the current directory,
- whose "git directory" is `/Volumes/My_USB/projectA_gitdir`,

simply run

```
git init --separate-git-dir="/Volumes/My_USB/projectA_gitdir"
```

To fix ideas,

- inspect the contents of the `.git` *file*:

  ```
  $ cat .git
  gitdir: /Volumes/My_USB/projectA_gitdir
  ```

  As you can see, it's just a text file containing the path to the git directory of your repo.
- inspect the config of your local repo, by running

  ```
  $ git config --local --list
  ```

  You should notice a line that isn't normally present when a repo has been initialised without the `--separate-git-dir` flag:

  ```
  core.worktree=<pwd>
  ```

  where `<pwd>` is the path to the current directory.
- inspect the contents of the git directory; if everything went well, a folder called `projectA_gitdir` must have been created on the USB drive and populated with everything that normally goes into the `.git` folder:

  ```
  $ ls /Volumes/My_USB/projectA_gitdir
  HEAD        description info        refs
  config      hooks       objects
  ```

  All good :)

Of course, you will only be able to run Git commands on this repo if the drive is accessible. For instance, after unmounting it, here is what happens:

```
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository: /Volumes/My_USB/projectA_gitdir
```