# How do I find where my git repository is located?

Tags: git

I'm not sure that when I entered `git init` that I was in the proper directory, and I'm afraid that I may have created a repository somewhere where I didn't want to. How can I find where I created my git repository?

I'm currently on OSX Mavericks

Comment: you are using nix or windows?

Comment: This is more of a Linux QA question not SO

Comment: Just do ls -a from within the same directory where git init was executed.....to delete , do :> rm -rf  .git/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command in Terminal:

```
find . -type d -name '.git'
```

This will list all subdirectories named `.git` in the current directory's subtree, indicative of a Git repository located in the respective parent directory.

Substitute a directory of interest for `.`, such as `~` to search your entire home dir.

Note that if you choose `/` to search your entire filesystem, you'll get permission-denied errors, unless you run with `sudo`.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it okay to enter exactly as you stated: `find . -type d -name '.git'`. Or is it necessary to enter in a directory in place of `.`?

Comment: @AlanH:  `.` represents the _current_ directory, so you can either `cd` to the directory of interest first to use the command as-is, or substitute a directory of interest for `.` - the output paths will be relative to whatever input path was specified.

Comment: so if I want to search the home directory, i.e.  *everything*, I should use `~`? http://www.sixarm.com/about/git-how-to-find-git-repository-directories.html

Comment: @AlanH: `~` represents your _home directory_ (generally, in POSIX-like shells such as in Bash on OSX, just like `.` always represents the current dir.), so, if you think you could have created the repo _anywhere in your home dir. or its subdirs. or their subdirs. ..._, then you should indeed use `~`. The `.` was just a placeholder to get you started, so you could pick a potentially _smaller_ subtree than your entire home dir., as that could take a while to search. But if performance is not a concern, try `~`.

Comment: One caveat: although the Git directory is generally located in a `.git` subfolder of the root project directory, this needs not be the case.

Comment: @Jubobs: Interesting; how do you do that and when would you choose to?

Comment: @mklement0 I've never felt the need to have a separate Git directory myself, but it can be done via `git init`'s `--separate-git-dir` option. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323960/how-can-i-set-up-the-working-directory-and-the-local-repository-on-different-dri/30327180#30327180 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It will create a repository in your current directory. and all the metadata is stored in `.git` in your current directory. If you don't want it, just delete `.git`

Comment: Yes, but I want to find the path to verify it's not stored somewhere I don't want it to be.

Comment: @AlanH - just use search functionality in your operating system and look for a directory called .git in your C or whatever drive

Comment: .git folder will be hidden in Windows. You can view the hidden folders by enabling them in your explorer using Tools > Folder Options... > View tab > Show hidden files, folders and drives. You can do this for all the directories where you typed `git init`; For OS X - http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/