# Can you keep the local git repo on a different drive than the working directory?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

I work with games (Unity 3D), which contains massive binary files that bloat my Git repository (even with LFS).  I need my working directory to be on my fast M.2 drive so my work pipeline is smooth, but there is very limited space on my M.2, so I need to keep the huge .git local repo directory on a different SSD drive that I use for storage.  Is it possible to put the huge .git repo directory on another drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up the working directory and the local repository on different drives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323960/how-can-i-set-up-the-working-directory-and-the-local-repository-on-different-dri)

Comment: Worth noting, the docs specify that even for an existing repo, running `init` with this flag can move the `.git` contents; so the top answer to that question really is likely the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: After working this way with Git for some time, I've come to realize that splitting the working directory can cause some strange bugs.  Once I reverted back to the standard setup (repo in same directory as working directory), I no longer had any bugs.  I'll leave my noted below in case anyone is curious how I had set it up, but I don't recommend doing it.

After some research, I found two sources that helped me come up with a solution, but I had authentication issues that prevented them from working.  Eventually I figured out how to just do it manually without the need of the console commands.  Essentially I did this:

1. Locate the .git folder in the working directory (the entire repo is in this single folder)
2. Cut and paste the .git folder into the location you want it stored (like the storage drive)
3. Inside the .git folder, locate the config file.  Open it with a text editor like Notepad++.
4. Under the [core] section, define the working directory with worktree.  Example:

   worktree = C:/MyProjects/MyGitWorkingTree

The entire [core] section might look something like this now:

```
[core]
    bare = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = C:/MyProjects/MyGitWorkingTree
[remote "origin"]
    [... the rest of the file is down here...]
```

5. Go back to your working directory (the exact directory you took the .git folder from) and create a new file called .git.  In windows to do this, you need to name the file .git. (note the last dot at end)
6. Open the new .git file you created with a text editor (like Notepad++). It should be completely empty when you open it since it's a new file.
7. Write a new line that is the exact path to the git directory you moved in step 2.  Example:

   gitdir: D:\MySeparatedGitRepo\.git

And if you follow those steps above, you should have a separated git repo that works like any normal repo without the need of the command line tools.

As a note, I personally have been pointing my GUI tools to read from the actual git repo on the storage drive, but I think you can also point them to the working directory.  They basically just point back and forth to each other if I understand it correctly.